# How to set blankText width?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

i have form with textfield allowBlank=false, and blankText='Inserire il motivo della richiesta'

In Firefox no problem, I read my text correctly: 
[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly0C5.jpg)

In Chrome I get blankText unreadeable because text is shown with small width :
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly0C5.jpg#1)

Anyone can tell me how to set blankText width, so I can read in all browsers?

Comment: It's a bug introduced by the Chrome 26. We're hoping to have a fix for Ext 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with another option: setting "msgTarget: 'title'", or "msgTarget: 'under'",
my blankText string works correctly and is fully visible on firefox, chrome, etc.